# Зачем использовать Python2 вместо Python3?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Почему некоторые продолжают использовать интерпретатор предыдущей версии, почему он еще не умер и не забыт?

Третья версия ушла далеко вперед (один async и новый GIL чего стоят), многие библиотеки были портированы (ранее, например, был повод использовать Py2 - OpenCV, но и ее портировали).

Единственный повод - поддержка старых проектов и невозможность переезда, но по-прежнему есть те, кто стартует новые проекты на Py2. Новые вопросы на StackOverflow появляются.

Зачем, какие очевидные причины?

Comment: Все упирается в нужные библиотеки. Если под 3 ветку их нет, то куда деваться.

Comment: _Новый_ GIL? То есть GIL так и остался?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, какие библиотеки? В 2016 не встречал ни одной незаменимой.
VladD, остался и останется до тех пор, пока не будет написано что-то более быстрое. Новый GIL, появившийся в версии 3.2 уменьшает overhead, когда потоки дерутся за обладание GIL.

Comment: @m9_psy последний раз было такое с ансиблем.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что если писать `from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function`, не забывать про разницу в делении и учитывать отсутствие некоторых модулей, то можно почти беспроблемно писать код для обоих версий. Плюс ещё модуль six по вкусу, но я обхожусь без него

Comment: @andreymal, это, к сожалению, не решает проблему старого кода...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Очевидной причиной является несовместимость большинства старых рабочих тестированных Питон 2 программ с Питон 3.

Даже если большинство изменений тривиально (и может быть автоматизированно), переход на Питон 3 требует наличия тестов и времени программистов, трату которого надо обосновать. Питон 2 сам по себе уже хорошим языком является. Питон 3 местами лучше, но для каких-то задач может даже хуже показаться на первый взгляд.

Даже если разработчики могут найти время для перехода на новый язык, учитывая что программисты люди любознательные, Питон 3 может конкурировать с переходом и на другие языки такие как Go, OCaml (Питон 3 несовместим, но он "недостаточно несовместим" если что-то новое хочется попробовать).

Изначальной адаптации Питона 3 не помогало, то что первые версии (до Питон 3.2-3.3) не были предназначены для широкого использования. Большинство книг/ресурсов в сети использовали Питон 2 синтаксис. Обычно, предустановленная команда `python` запускает Питон 2 на POSIX системах.

Большинство живых популярных библиотек работают как на Питоне 2 так и 3. Существует "длинный хвост" библиотек, которые только на Питоне 2 работают (публичные и внутренние инструменты).

Из-за заявленной долгосрочной (на данный момент до 2020) официальной поддержки Питона 2, люди немного теряют оставаясь на Питоне 2 (хотя люди часто недооценивают время жизни программ).

Заставлять программистов учить разницу между текстом, представленным в
виде Unicode строк и байтами создаёт заметный барьер для смены версий
для нового кода. Особенно, если программист работает в окружении где
текст в основном представлен в виде байт, закодированных в utf-8, или
хуже: семантически текстовые интерфейсы используют исторически
байтовые API на POSIX системах, которые допускают произвольные
последовательности байтов (имена файлов, параметры командной строки,
переменные окружения), что требует таких вещей как surrogateescape,
чтобы продолжить с Unicode работать по умолчанию.

### Уроки

Чтобы не повторять ошибок, можно было бы избежать смены основной версии и
вводить новые изменения поэтапно (Python 4 в понимании Python 3 не должно быть):

- не накапливать много несовместимых изменений, которые нужно
  научиться использовать и искать способ подружить со старым кодом
  (низкая стоимость перехода)
- возможно большинство новых фич убрать под `from __future__ import
  division, print_function, unicode_literals, etc`, которая включается
  через несколько выпусков по умолчанию (позволяет тестировать,
  преобразовывать код по одному модулю за раз)
- публиковать на PyPI модули, облегчающие переход с версии на версию,
  например, `contextlib2`, `pathlib2`, `subprocess32`, etc
- предоставить возможность исполнять старый код на новой версии без
  изменений (чтобы старые программы поддерживать—это относительно
  просто, если другие пункты также реализовать)
- конвертировать новую версию в старую, чтобы новый код в старом
  окружении исполнять (новые программы можно было бы на новой версии
  языка писать, а исполнять в старом окружении) (3to2 вместо
  2to3—см. [`futurize` и `pasturize`
  скрипты](http://python-future.org/overview.html))
- ограничить поддержку старых версий (как сейчас 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5
  поддерживаются) — только одна официальная текущая версия языка
  (чтобы ненужный выбор не создавать)
- использование semver для языка может быть вредно по психологическим
  причинам: вместо 3.0 можно было 2.6 выпустить с меньшим набором
  новых фич (изменение основной цифры может пугать без оснований)
- медленно убирать старые особо зловредные фичи — упомянуть в
  документации лучший путь, но фактически задержать на несколько лет
  удаление старого кода (адаптация под каждую новую версию в любом
  случае может требовать работы—так барьер между перехода на каждую
  версию не слишком высок)

В итоге:

- люди, которые любят новые блестящие штучки, могут их использовать,
  не ожидая перехода всей кодовой базы на новую версию
- люди, которым надо чтоб продолжало работать, также довольны—старый
  код не должен ломаться (за исключением обычного ожидаемого
  подкручивания гаек при переходе на новую версию)
- особо консервативные люди продолжают сидеть на Python 2.4, 2.6
- новички просто начинают с текущей единственной версии

Answer (score 7):

Для меня одной из очевидных причин являются всяческие UNIX/Linux дистрибутивы, где по умолчанию стоит Python2 и у львиной доли простых юзеров нет прав, чтобы поставить Python 3 на уровне системы. Следовательно все их наработки не будут правильно (если специально этим не озаботиться) работать у остальных юзеров на Python 2.

Вот когда все популярные дистрибутивы будут выходить с Python 3 по-умолчанию, тогда можно будет постепенно начинать забывать про Python 2, IMO...

Comment: На многих дистрибутивах, Py3 уже в комплекте идет и ставить ничего не надо, только библиотеки. А надежды, что Py3 станет по-умолчанию, учитывая осторожность мэйнтейнеров, нету. Когда в Debian Py3 станет интерпретатором по-умолчанию, можно будет говорить, что мир вверх тормашками перевернулся.

Comment: @m9_psy, ну например у нас на фирме  X __тысяч__ серверов работают под  RedHat 5 - 7 и что делать? Python3 доступен только через SCL и требует определенных процедур с шаманским бубном, чтобы работать с ним. Плюс все "нажитое непосильным трудом" (legacy scripts, etc.)...

Comment: @MaxU рано или поздно это всё всё равно придётся обновлять, и по-моему лучше не ждать, когда наступит поздно :)

Comment: @andreymal, "не в бровь, а в глаз" !

Comment: @andreymal, а зачем? Питон все же скриптовый язык. А как большинство работает с такими языками? -- ищет подходящий скрипт, подкручивает для себя и вперед. И никакого углубленного изучения, тем более никаких новых версий, отличных от работающей (если она позволяет делать то, что конкретно тут нужно) люди и знать не хотят. Поэтому второй Питон это надолго (м.б. навсегда)

Comment: @avp а я тут про редхат

Comment: @andreymal, и я во многом про него (у заказчика пара сотен машин с RH 5.8 (Python 2.4.3))

Comment: @m9_psy некоторые дистрибутивы уже перешли на Py3 по-умолчанию, например Arch и основанные на нем дистрибутивы. Так что надежда есть таки.

Comment: @avp ну тогда потом не плакайте от невозможности установить что-нибудь современное и нужное, а также после слива данных через уязвимости в неподдерживаемом ПО :D

Comment: @andreymal, у Вас есть данные, которые в самом деле кто-то желает за большие деньги купить? Если да, так продайте за сходную цену, а если нет, то к чему эти страшилки?

Comment: @avp у фирмы с X тысячами серверов такие данные почти наверняка есть ;)

Comment: @andreymal, не надо инсинуаций! ;) на всех серверах регулярно накатываются свежие security patches и контролируется это тоже очень регулярно и строго, разными независимыми аудиторскими компаниями. Это кстати одна из причин сидеть на RedHat...

Comment: @MaxU но в любом случае поддержка старых версий редхата кончится "рано или поздно" и см. мой первый коммент)

Comment: @andreymal, отвечу вопросом на вопрос - много ли вы знаете крупных фирм, которые уже перешли на Windows 10? ;)

Comment: @andreymal, не буду спорить о том, в новой или старой версии больше *еще не найденных* ошибок. Просто скажу о том, что если у старой версии много пользователей, то всегда найдется достаточное количество людей, желающих поддерживать и распространять ее, даже независимо от устремлений лидера (толкающего новую версию).

Comment: COBOL, тоже, раньше был очень популярным.

Answer (score 5):

python2 и python3 сейчас одинаково популярны, для python2 продолжают писать библиотеки, улучшать. В чём-то синтаксис python2 лучше чем у python3, удобнее.
К примеру print по моему удобнее писать без скобок. для python2 есть модули которых не сделали для python3. Тем более python 2.7 у меня стоял с самого начала, многие не хотят отвыкать от python2 синтаксиса - поэтому на нём работают многие

Вообщем одновременно востребованы две параллельно развивающиеся версии языка Python — 2 и 3.

Comment: да, мне тоже print удобнее без скобок....

Answer (score 1):

Неочевидная проблема, об которую сам как-то обжегся: даже если библиотекой заявлена поддержка Python 3, еще неизвестно какого она качества. Например, год-два назад сделал попытку перейти на Py3: нужен был Pyserial, так он глючил на элементарных вещах, при том что с Py2 работал без проблем, пришлось вернуться на Py2.

Также в комменте годичной давности на Hacker News, говорилось что есть аналогичная проблема с Machine Learning библиотеками: есть поддержка Py3, но они забагованнее и поэтому народ все равно использует Py2.

В комменте (март 2016) к статье мейнтейнер библиотек говорит что баги проявляющиеся на Py3 месяцами висят, потому что все на Py2. Оригинал:
"A trove classifier says nothing about the quality of running a polyglot library on Python 2 or Python 3. I say this as someone who maintains polyglot libraries where I’ve had Python 3 bugs persist for months, because everyone actually uses Python 2."
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/03/08/python-3-is-winning/